# Iterate through XmlNode reached with foreach XmlNodeList loop?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

This is my code to iterate through our xml file. With the foreach loop and the IF condition that checks for the only one instance of "CounterSales" in the whole XML file, I get the node that includes all the relevant information.

Here's the code, it's very simple:

```
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//nd/ni");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    if (node.OuterXml.Contains("CounterSales"))
    {
        // I'm in the correct node. Iterate through this node. How?
    }
}
```

Now that I'm already here, I need to iterate through `node`. This is what the `node.OuterXml` of this particular node looks like when the `IF` statement is true:

```
<ni>
    <nss>20150927</nss>
    <gp>Addon</gp>
    <ns>CounterBlah1</ns>
    <ns>CounterBlah2</ns>
    <ns>CounterSales</ns>
    <ns>CounterBlah4</ns>
    <ns>CounterBlah5</ns>
    <ns>CounterBlah6</ns>
    <nv>
        <nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=132</nad>
        <r>0</r>
        <r>15</r>
        <r>8</r>
        <r>3</r>
        <r>2</r>
        <r>2</r>
    </nv>
    <nv>
        <nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=433</nad>
        <r>0</r>
        <r>15</r>
        <r>30</r>
        <r>3</r>
        <r>2</r>
        <r>2</r>
    </nv>
    <nv>
        <nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=665</nad>
        <r>0</r>
        <r>15</r>
        <r>90</r>
        <r>3</r>
        <r>2</r>
        <r>2</r>
    </nv>
</ni>
```

`CounterSales` is the 3rd node, which means that I will need to get the ID in every `<nad>`, and then get the the 3rd `<r>` value of every .

The final result would be:

```
132, 8
433, 30
665, 90
```

Currently, I'm assuming that the 3rd `<r>` value is the one that I'm interested in. In the future, I should count *where* `<ns>CounterSales</ns>` and read the appropriate number, but that's not necessary now.

Thanks again.

Comment: Do you *have* to use XmlNodeList etc? Almost everything is simpler with LINQ to XML :)

Comment: You're probably right; sooner or later I'll have to deal with that. But it seems that debugging and breakpoints is slightly harder since a lot is being done with very little code.

Comment: I'd rather have less code to debug, personally... I suppose the XML format itself can't be changed? (It's a pretty nasty format, IMO...) It's doable with the current format, but not fun.

Comment: But now's as good a time as any to learn, so I'll test using linq-to-xml.

Comment: I wish I could change the format, but unfortunately that's literally impossible.

Comment: So I would separate this into two tasks: 1) once you've found the right `ns` element, work out its index (count the preceding siblings); 2) apply that index to the `r` elements within each `nv` element (use `nvElement.Elements("r").ElementAt(index)`)

Comment: Here's a thought: it wouldn't be terribly hard to write code to transform this document format into a nicer one. So you could still take the nasty one as input, but then process it into a nice one and work with that internally. Is that a useful idea for you?

Comment: If the XML file were more manageable, I'd be more open to testing new ideas. But the format plus the sheer size of the file turns this into an unpleasant task.

Comment: That makes sense. The file itself is about 1M lines, but the usable section is about 100K lines.

Comment: And do you use the same file for multiple queries? If so, creating an in-memory *non-XML* representation (before you look for any specific item) could be another idea. Unfortunately I don't have the time to write the code for any of these right now, although maybe later...

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have to be XML. In this case, I thought it would be easier to iterate through an `XmlNode` the same way I moved through the `XmlNodeList`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could do it. The idea is to iterate all the `<ns>` nodes, to determine the index of the node with the value "CounterSales". We then use that index to select the related `<r>`.

I also made a change to the way the initial `<ni>` is selected. The way you had it, the value "CounterSales" appearing anywhere within OuterXml could give you a false match. This way uses an XPath expression containing a predicate.

```
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

// Use XPath to find <ni> that contain CounterSales, rather than use string comparison
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//nd/ni[ns='CounterSales']");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    XmlNodeList nsNodes = node.SelectNodes("ns");

    // Get index of "CountersSales" within <ni>
    int index = 0;

    while (index < nsNodes.Count)
    {
        if (nsNodes[index].InnerText == "CounterSales")
            break;

        index++;
    }

    // Search through <nv>
    XmlNodeList nvNodes = node.SelectNodes("nv");

    foreach (XmlElement nvNode in nvNodes)
    {
        XmlNode nadNode = nvNode.SelectSingleNode("nad");

        // Get the stuff after the last equals sign. Possibly use regex here instead.
        string id = nadNode.InnerText.Substring(nadNode.InnerText.LastIndexOf('=') + 1);

        // XPathQuery for r element at our index (position in xpath is 1-based, rather than 0-based like C#)
        string rQuery = String.Format("r[position() = {0}]", index + 1);

        XmlNode rNode = nvNode.SelectSingleNode(rQuery);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", id, rNode.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a helper function with linq make code very simple

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<ni>" +
                    "<nss>20150927</nss>" +
                    "<gp>Addon</gp>" +
                    "<ns>CounterBlah1</ns>" +
                    "<ns>CounterBlah2</ns>" +
                    "<ns>CounterSales</ns>" +
                    "<ns>CounterBlah4</ns>" +
                    "<ns>CounterBlah5</ns>" +
                    "<ns>CounterBlah6</ns>" +
                    "<nv>" +
                        "<nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=132</nad>" +
                        "<r>0</r>" +
                        "<r>15</r>" +
                        "<r>8</r>" +
                        "<r>3</r>" +
                        "<r>2</r>" +
                        "<r>2</r>" +
                    "</nv>" +
                    "<nv>" +
                        "<nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=433</nad>" +
                        "<r>0</r>" +
                        "<r>15</r>" +
                        "<r>30</r>" +
                        "<r>3</r>" +
                        "<r>2</r>" +
                        "<r>2</r>" +
                    "</nv>" +
                    "<nv>" +
                        "<nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=665</nad>" +
                        "<r>0</r>" +
                        "<r>15</r>" +
                        "<r>90</r>" +
                        "<r>3</r>" +
                        "<r>2</r>" +
                        "<r>2</r>" +
                    "</nv>" +
                "</ni>";

            XElement ni = XElement.Parse(input);
            var results1 = ni.Descendants("nv").Select(x => new
            {
                nad = x.Element("nad").Value,
                r = x.Elements("r").Select(y => y.Value).ToList()
            }).ToList();

            var results2 = results1.Select(x => new {
                Id = Helper(x.nad, "Id"),
                r = int.Parse(x.r[2])
            }).ToList();

        }
        static int? Helper(string csv, string name)
        {
            int? results = null;
            string pattern = @"(?'name'\w+)=(?'value'\d+)";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(csv, pattern);
            foreach(Match match in matches)
            {
                string csvName = match.Groups["name"].Value;
                if(csvName == name)
                {
                    results = int.Parse(match.Groups["value"].Value);
                    break;
                }

            }
            return results;

        }
    }
}
​
```